# Shell scripting error: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Can someone explain to me why the following shell script line throws this error:

Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: yes: There is an unexpected '('. I suppose you know that ;-). What are you trying to do?

Comment: you might escape the parens: \\(name=default userid=$from \
            send=$TMP/`basename $1`\\)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell scripts expect variables to be set in the pattern of:

```
VARIABLE=value
```

You can't have any additional = signs in there. However, you can execute other scripts like this:

```
VARIABLE=$(basename $1)
VARIABLE=`basename $1`
```

Either one works.

In your case, I can't tell what you're doing, but it isn't right at all. My guess is that you need to do this:

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(basename $1)
```